Question about Lipschitz continuity of Frobenius norm
Suppose $\sigma: \mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is a matrix function and that there exist $\alpha \ge 0$ and $\hat\sigma: \mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ so that $$\sigma(x)\sigma^T(x) = \alpha I + \hat\sigma(x)\hat\sigma^T(x), \forall x\in \mathbb R. $$ If $\hat\sigma$ satisfies $$\|\hat\sigma(x)- \hat\sigma(y) \|^2_F \le K |x-y|^2,\ \  \forall x, y\in \mathbb R,$$ where $K> 0$ is a constant, can we prove or disprove that $$\|\sigma(x)- \sigma(y) \|^2_F \le K |x-y|^2, \ \ \forall x, y\in \mathbb R?$$ Here $I$ is the identity matrix and $\|A\|_F :=\sqrt{Tr(A^T A)} $ is the Frobenius norm of the matrix $A$.
Thanks for your help.

Is  $\sigma(x)\sigma^T(y)=\alpha I + \hat\sigma(x)\hat\sigma^T(y), \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$?

I don't know. At least I don't have a proof.
